# Cover entire div with image

Tags: css, joomla, entity-framework-4, background-image

for my joomla 3.x website i'm using a template based on the EF4 framework. I assigned width "5" to position top2-1 and "7" to position top2-2.
I wanted to create a custom html module for the homepage (http://francescaleso.com/it/) in position top2-1 to show a background image completely filling it. 
I have tried as suggested on this site doing like this:

```
.homeimg {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(/images/headers/home-image.jpg);
}
```

And the module only has

```
 <div class="homeimg"></div>
```

The path of the image is correct, because if i try "open in new tab" it gets displayed correctly, however it won't show on my homepage.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want to include the full image inside the div that has `class="span5"`. So to achieve that I just changed your `<div class="homeimg"></div>` to `<img src="http://francescaleso.com/images/headers/home-image.jpg">` and worked. I hope this solves your problem! Here is a screenshot of how it looks like: [Imgur](http://imgur.com/vQjGA5y)

Comment: If doing so, i get this: http://francescaleso.com/it/
And as you can see it doesn't cover the area completely. if you look at the example on the comment below you'll see what i'd like to achieve.

Plus, i'd like it to be 100% height (and so fill the page vertically if not scrolled) but not horizontally

Answer (score 1):

Make these modifications in the CSS.

```
.homeimg {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(/images/headers/home-image.jpg);

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Doing so won't help, since the image gets to cover the totality of the page getting over all the other content, whilst i need it to cover just the upper left portion of it.
Here's an example of what i'm **desperately** trying to achieve:
http://www.joomla.it/template/8718-ohio-template-only-v1-0.html

I honestly don't have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

----edit--- if i play a bit with absolute and relative positions, i get this: 
the problem is that the image isn't the full height of the unscrolled space, and also has an unwanted padding or something on the left...